# Sveltekit not running JavaScript on iOS

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have [sveltekit website](https://web-servey.vercel.app/debug), (on opening the site "Collecting logs..." must change to " Copy Logs " in 5sec, if not then JavaScript must not be running).

For some reason svelte is not running my website correctly on iOS, after some feedback (from users), I concluded JavaScript is not running at all in iOS browsers. I don't have "mac" or "iPhone", so can't show you the console. Site runs perfectly on Android & Windows. Am I missing some configuration here?

I did lot of research, and everything I found so far was a dead end. Is this how it will be with sveltekit, if so then should I will use Next.js then?

src/routes/debug/+page.svelte

```html
<script lang="ts">
    // ... code
</script>
{#await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 5000))}
    <button disabled class="-bg-base2 bg-opacity-50 px-2 py-1 w-full mt-3">
        Collecting logs...
    </button>
{:then _}
    <button class="-bg-base2 px-2 py-1 w-full mt-3" on:click={copyLogs}>  Copy Logs  </button>
{/await}
<!-- <MyUI /> -->
```

package.json

```json
{
    "name": "survey-site",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fontsource/merriweather": "^4.5.14",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.37",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.27.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.27.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "eslint": "^8.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.16",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.7.1",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.7",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4",
        "vite": "^3.0.4"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^9.9.4",
        "svelte-drawer-component": "^1.2.2"
    }
}
```

svelte.config.js

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess({ postcss: true }),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

vite.config.ts

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

const config: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
};

export default config;
```

Comment: does safari block alert? I seem to recall that it does somewhere.

Comment: for me it looks like it is running js but there are some issues with API that you are using:
(`Fetch API cannot load https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fhuddle-and-score%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=73F7w7KaKwlXFXEZhGarv897bSa2DEJz&VER=8&RID=rpc&SID=X1tqejTOkoI0C9tKkgjz9A&CI=0&AID=9&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=i25itnlu6f1q&t=1 due to access control checks.`)
Maybe this will give you some hint where to look :D

Comment: @chovy even if alert is not supported in safari, the buttons just don't work.

Comment: alert is blocking....that's why its blocked. I'm on linux so I'm afraid I'm of no help.

Comment: @PawełWąsowski I can't see this error on [Windows Chrome](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/huddle-and-score.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202022-10-04%20123700.png?alt=media&token=6f42e761-89bc-4623-923c-af6260a7f5f4). Besides, fetch is an async call, why will that affect buttons and rest UI based JavaScript

Comment: @chovy alright I have removed alert dialog from my site. Could you check if it buttons works on your machine?

Comment: If you have Apple users, you should invest in either such devices or a test service that allows you to test on these devices.

Comment: @H.B. you are right but man our product is not that big yet. I just want a solution/insight, no lectures.

Comment: @Panth now I can see some data after the change (Safari). Before there was additional error after the fetch but I cannot remember it content. It looked like some out of range exception - maybe iteration over data that was not returned by the API?

Maybe you can try to use:
https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-safari-browser
I can see that they have some kind of free trial.

Comment: @PawełWąsowski I tried that here is the [output](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/huddle-and-score.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202022-10-04%20133104.png?alt=media&token=b8728c58-e337-4ba3-8fa6-74bae37c9ccb)

Comment: @Panth yeah, I'm reciving same output. The issue is this unhandled promise rejection that blocks rest of the js, but I cannot help you with that - I don't know what the issue is :/
That promise that you've included in question works correctly on Safari, so issue is probably somewhere else. My bet is some quirk that needs to be handled differently on Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find your repo on GitHub and found the issue - the following expressions throw an error in Safari. This is not a SvelteKit bug, but an issue with your code:

```js
new Date(new Date().toString() + ' UTC'); // returns "Invalid Date"
new Date(new Date().toString() + ' UTC').toISOString().substring(0, 16); // throws "RangeError: Invalid Date"
```

I'm not sure whether Safari is right to throw an error here or not (i.e. whether the spec permits it), but either way it's not going to work in Safari.

Because this code throws an exception, your component is unable to successfully hydrate and you only see the server-side-rendered output ("Collecting logs..." never updates).

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be able to use some of the built-in [Date UTC methods instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#static_methods).

Comment: u would't belive but i did resolve the problem, and yes this was the problem. just 5 min ago.
turns out UTC dosent work in safari.. . Man problem is resolved. TYSM